# Opening a CSV file and saving the same CSV with a different name and filepath

Tags: excel, vba

OK so I am having trouble trying to open a file with the name "testymctesttest_0001a.csv" then rename then save the same file with just the name "001a" to a different folder. I'm trying to do this on roughly 700 files in a given folder. Some have a letter at the end of the number (ex. 0001a) and some do not have the letter (ex 0218). Is there a way to do this without copying all the csv data into a workbook just to save that workbook as another CSV? I tried the code below and everything worked except all the newly saved CSV data was corrupted in the new folder.

```
Sub openSavefile()

Dim filePaths() As String
Dim lineFromFile As String
Dim lineItems() As String
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim actWkb As Workbook
Dim ary() As String
Dim ary2() As String
Dim fPath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Line1:
filePaths = selectFilesFunc

If filePaths(1) = "0" Then
   Exit Sub
End If
If filePaths(1) = "-1" Then
   GoTo Line1
End If

For j = 1 To UBound(filePaths)

Workbooks.Add
Set actWkb = ActiveWorkbook
Cells(1, 1).Activate
rowNum = 0

ary = Split(filePaths(j), "\")
ary2 = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), "_")
ary = Split(ary2(UBound(ary2)), ".")

Cells(1, 10).Value = ary(0)
fPath = "H:\TEST\FR2\"

Open filePaths(j) For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, lineFromFile
    lineItems = Split(lineFromFile, ",")
    If UBound(lineItems) < 4 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(lineItems)
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, i).Value = lineItems(i)
        Next i
    Else
        If lineItems(7) = "HEX" Then
            Range("D" & rowNum + 1 & ":G" & rowNum + 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            'Range("D" & rowNum + 1 & ":G" & rowNum + 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End If

        For i = 0 To UBound(lineItems)
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, i).Value = lineItems(i)
        Next i
    End If
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
Loop
actWkb.SaveAs fPath & ary(0) & ".csv"
actWkb.Close
Close #1
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

The Function selectFilesFunc just gets an array of file paths to open. and the array index ary(0) just holds the new file name to be saved as (ex 0001a or 0218).

I have searched many places to find an answer and I feel like it is a simple command I am missing. But my final goal is just to open the CSV using Open filePaths(j) For Input As #1 or something similar and just save that same file with the new name and file path. But if I have to import it to a workbook to then save as a CSV, then I would like to know how to do this without corrupting the data.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you just renaming to whatever is after the underscore in the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it without opening the file.
It just renames the file to the text after the last underscore and moves the file from `sSourceFolder` to `sDestinationFolder`:

```
Public Sub RenameAndMove()

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim sSourceFolder As String
    Dim sDestinationFolder As String

    Set colFiles = New Collection
    sSourceFolder = "S:\DB_Development_DBC\Test\"
    sDestinationFolder = "S:\DB_Development_DBC\Test1\"

    EnumerateFiles sSourceFolder, "*.csv", colFiles

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each vFile In colFiles
        'Get the new filename.
        sFileName = Mid(vFile, InStrRev(vFile, "_") + 1, Len(vFile))
        On Error Resume Next
            'Move the file.
            oFSO.movefile vFile, sDestinationFolder & sFileName
            'You can delete this row if you want.
            'It states whether the move was successful in the Immediate window.
            Debug.Print vFile & " = " & (Err.Number = 0)
        Err.Clear
    Next vFile

End Sub

Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef cCollection As Collection)

    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        cCollection.Add sDirectory & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You are amazing. This worked flawlessly. You my friend have saved me about 4 hours of manual renaming! Thank you for your response